# SQL Server : I am working on for time checkin giving error that can not repeat columns with same name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am creating a sql for checkin time for employees.

My table looks like this

[image]

I want to display checkin time for employees.

So for example jason timesheet will look something like this

```
name   | 1st feb  | 2nd feb  | 3rd feb
----------------------------------------------------    
jason  |  9:00:00 |  9:00:00 | ...
clark  |  ...     |  ...     | ...
```

I have found a similar question here  [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

But it's not quite working

output that I am getting[image]

**Updated:**following is my sql

```
     DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(checkin)                    
                from cico
                group by checkin, id
                order by id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

  set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select checkin, name
            from cico
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(checkin)
            for name in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

        exec sp_executesql @query;
     END
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample test data

Comment: You need to pivot this table, what have you tried so far that you are saying its not working?

Comment: I have posted output that I am getting

Comment: I am posted what I have done so far

Comment: Well firstly instead of pivoting on `checkin` you should pivot on `DateT`. Secondly if you want a nicely formatted report, use a report writer, not T-SQL

Comment: Ideally, perform this sort of transformation in a reporting tool or your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Get all dates and format it in CSV string
SELECT @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DateT)
            FROM cico
            GROUP BY DateT
            ORDER BY DateT
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

-- The pivot query 
SET @query = N'SELECT name, ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select checkin, name, DateT
            from cico
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(checkin)
            for DateT in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

PRINT @query  -- print out the query

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: do a PRINT @query to see the result. It will help you to understand it

Comment: in short it is using dynamic sql to perform the pivoting

Comment: hi @squirrel, if I am working on sql server ssrs report. can I use `Matrix` to achieve this outcome that you answered?

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with SSRS.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

I have edited your query...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DateT)                    
                from cico
                group by DateT
                order by DateT
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

  set @query = N'SELECT name,' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select name,DateT,checkin
            from cico
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(checkin)
            for DateT in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

        exec sp_executesql @query;
     END
```

Comment: now it give two error:Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The incorrect value "09:00:10.0000000" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Comment: hi @SankarRaj, if I am working on sql server ssrs report. can I use `Matrix` to achieve this outcome that you answered?

Comment: I want the same result on presentation layer. so i am asking can I achieve the above with `matrix`?